# Converting UIKit ImagePicker to SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm finding it tough to convert this so that it works in a swiftUI view. I have tried my own variations but the function 'getVideofromCameraRoll' which has an 'on' parameter doesn't work in a SwiftUI view as it's a UIViewController and not ContentView. Appreciate all the help I can get, I'm relatively new to this :(

This image picker takes in video and generates a thumbnail for that video.

```
class PhotoServices: NSObject {
static let shared = PhotoServices()

internal var completion: ((URL)->Void)!
internal let picker = UIImagePickerController()

override init() {
    
    super.init()
    
    self.picker.allowsEditing = false
    self.picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    self.picker.delegate = self
    
}

   func getVideoFromCameraRoll(on: UIViewController, completion: @escaping (_ image: URL)->()) {
    
    self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    self.picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        on.present(self.picker, animated: true) {
            self.completion = completion
             }
          }
       }
    }


   //// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods

   extension PhotoServices: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
   UINavigationControllerDelegate {
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    
    if let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
                
                self.completion(url)
                
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }

////// MARK: Thumbnail
  extension PhotoServices {


func getThumbnailFrom(path: URL) -> UIImage? {
    
    do {
        
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: path , options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: 
nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        
        return thumbnail
        
    } catch let error {
        
        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
        
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Hi Matt, apologies my ask wasn't clear. I am reaching out for help to convert this image picker so that it works in a swiftUI View because currently in that form, it isn't compatitble.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.